# Complex arrays in C++ - real part, imag part

Tags: c++, arrays, complex-numbers

please can you help me with my problem with complex arrays in C++? If I have an array Arr[N] of cmplx numbers and now I need the real part of the Arr[i]. In header there is an complex array CompArray defined as

```
cmplx** CompArray;
```

and then I allocate it to have dimension [nmax][nmax]

then I have a function1 where I use only part of this and write

```
myclass::function1(double* realArray)
realArray = new double [nmax];
cmplx* ComplexArray [nmax];
ComplexArray[] = CompArray[10][];
for(int i=0;nmax;i++){
    realArray[i] = ComplexArray[i].real();
}
```

I get an error:

```
error: expression must have class type
```

the error is the same for real() or imag() functions

Answer (score 2):

```
cmplx* ComplexArray [nmax];
```

That's not an array of complex numbers; it's an array of pointers to numbers. It looks like you need a pointer to (the first of) an array of numbers:

```
cmplx* ComplexArray = CompArray[10];
```

Then `ComplexArray[i]` is a complex number (an expression with "class type") as required.

Once you've fixed that, this looks a bit dodgy:

```
realArray = new double [nmax];
```

You've been passed a pointer, then you throw it away and allocate a new array. The caller won't see that array, so all you've done is leak memory. You *could* pass the pointer by reference, or return it from the function; that way the caller will at least get the results.

However, it's a bad idea to pass around raw pointers to dynamic memory and hope they get deleted at the right time. Instead, pass around objects which are responsible for managing the memory; in this case, a container would be ideal:

```
std::vector<double> myclass::function1() {
    std::vector<double> realArray;
    cmplx* ComplexArray = CompArray[10];
    for(int i=0;i<nmax;i++){
        realArray.push_back(ComplexArray[i].real();
    }
    return realArray;
}
```